# Unwrapping JSON arrays into Swift objects

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I'm new to Swift and trying to unwrap an HTTP response into Swift objects. Below is the format of the response that I get.

```
{
    "data": {
        "task": [
            {
                "id": "65eea256-e497-4426-b462-18790bdaf9da",
                "title": "First task",
                "user_id": "zR3vTSf771crIau65gkrZnVzRIj2",
                "updated_at": "2021-06-09T18:38:45.300793+00:00",
                "created_at": "2021-06-09T18:38:45.300793+00:00"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to convert the above JSON array of `"task"` into a Swift array of `[Task]`.

**Problem:** The `"task"` part is the only thing that varies across API call results. In other words, if I were to query for *projects*, it would say `"project"` (in place of "task") in the JSON while keeping the overall structure same.

Here's my attempt to make the result generic, but I'm missing the JSON property `"task"`. If I add the property in the struct, then it won't be reusable across queries and I'd end up with a result struct per type.

```
struct Result<T:Codable> : Codable {
    let data: [T]
}
```

This maps to (which is wrong!)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "65eea256-e497-4426-b462-18790bdaf9da",
            "title": "First task",
            "user_id": "zR3vTSf771crIau65gkrZnVzRIj2",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-09T18:38:45.300793+00:00",
            "created_at": "2021-06-09T18:38:45.300793+00:00"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please, don't call your objects `Result`. That will collide with `Swift.Result`.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for pointing that out. Definitely something new for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything you want if you write the decoding process manually:

```
struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: [T]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RawCodingKey.self)
        guard let firstKey = container.allKeys.first else {
            throw ResponseError.couldNotFindData
        }
        data = try container.decode([T].self, forKey: firstKey)
    }

    private enum ResponseError: String, Error {
        case couldNotFindData
    }

    private struct RawCodingKey: CodingKey {
        let stringValue: String
        let intValue: Int? = nil

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
 }
```

I have written only the decoding process because encoding would be a bigger problem.

Also note that any other key inside `data` will break it. Of course, you could also use `allKeys.filter { ... }` to filter out other data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I'm assuming the `else` part decodes to the coding key that i want i.e. I can say `.project` and it should work alright. I've got trouble understanding the `if` statement and what exactly is `singleValueContainer()`.

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria I missed the part about `project` in your question. Is there always only one key? Then you could probably make it even more dynamic by enumerating the keys and taking the first one. See the methods on `container`. A single value container is basically anything that you want to decode as a whole. It just takes everything that is passed down to this decoder.

Comment: So it always starts with `"data"`, then it can be `"task"`, `"project"`, `subtask"` or anything. Then the JSON array is mapped to the relevant type `T`.  I'll go through `container()` and `singleValueContainer()` to understand it better!

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria Updated, not it will just take the first key and decode `[T]` from it.

Comment: I think this is precisely what I need, but I'll definitely try this out and let you know. Regarding "note that any other key inside data will break it." -- I only get "data" or "errors" in the JSON but not both, so I think this should be okay.

Comment: There is one small issue in the answer. We've two containers (one for `data` and the other for `todo`). I had to create a nested container and then call `nested.decode([T].self, forKey: entityKey)` for it to work. Please make an edit so that it is factually correct!