# Custom JSON decoding: decode an array of different objects in several distinct arrays

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I need your help to implement a custom JSON decoding. The JSON returned by the API is:

```
{
  "zones": [
    {
      "name": "zoneA",
      "blocks": [
        // an array of objects of type ElementA
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoneB",
      "blocks": [
        // an array of objects of type ElementB
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoneC",
      "blocks": [
        // an array of objects of type ElementC
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoneD",
      "blocks": [
        // an array of objects of type ElementD
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't want to parse this JSON as an array of zones with no meaning. I'd like to produce a model with an array for every specific type of block, like this:

```swift
struct Root {
    let elementsA: [ElementA]
    let elementsB: [ElementB]
    let elementsC: [ElementC]
    let elementsD: [ElementD]
}
```

How can I implement the `Decodable` protocol (by using `init(from decoder:)`) to follow this logic? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46319139/how-to-decode-an-array-of-values-whose-types-depend-on-a-tag) can be helpful.

Comment: Check this out. It might help -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67940691/unwrapping-json-arrays-into-swift-objects

Comment: Can you distinct an `ElementA` from an `ElementB`? I mean with "real difference" in what are they properties, etc.? Does the `name` properties is linked to the kind of elements?

Comment: @Larme I should use the name property of the zone to distinguish the elements.

Comment: What if more than one block for each zone in the array?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini thanks for trying to help guys  this cannot happen since the API returns just an array of blocks for each zone.

Comment: Probably the easiest is to create something like an `AnyZone` that can contain any zone and knows how to create your specific zone types so you decode a temporary  array of those, and before you return from `Root.init(from:)`  you loop through that array to map individual elements into their specific types, appending them to their corresponding array.

Comment: It’s also possible to write your own custom decoder that works with `Codable`, but that’s kind of a heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a solution with nested containers. With the given (simplified but valid) JSON string

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "zones": [
    {
      "name": "zoneA",
      "blocks": [
        {"name": "Foo"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoneB",
      "blocks": [
        {"street":"Broadway", "city":"New York"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoneC",
      "blocks": [
        {"email": "foo@bar.com"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "zoneD",
      "blocks": [
        {"phone": "555-01234"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

and the corresponding element structs

```
struct ElementA : Decodable { let name: String }
struct ElementB : Decodable { let street, city: String }
struct ElementC : Decodable { let email: String }
struct ElementD : Decodable { let phone: String }
```

first decode the `zones` as `nestedUnkeyedContainer` then iterate the array and decode first the `name` key and depending on `name` the elements.

Side note: This way requires to declare the element arrays as `var`iables.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    var elementsA = [ElementA]()
    var elementsB = [ElementB]()
    var elementsC = [ElementC]()
    var elementsD = [ElementD]()

    enum Zone: String, Decodable { case zoneA, zoneB, zoneC, zoneD }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case zones }
    private enum ZoneCodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, blocks }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var zonesContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .zones)
        while !zonesContainer.isAtEnd {
            let item = try zonesContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ZoneCodingKeys.self)
            let zone = try item.decode(Zone.self, forKey: .name)
            switch zone {
                case .zoneA: elementsA = try item.decode([ElementA].self, forKey: .blocks)
                case .zoneB: elementsB = try item.decode([ElementB].self, forKey: .blocks)
                case .zoneC: elementsC = try item.decode([ElementC].self, forKey: .blocks)
                case .zoneD: elementsD = try item.decode([ElementD].self, forKey: .blocks)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Decoding the stuff is straightforward

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hah! Just finished ten mins ago going through this with a colleague and then it's the first thing I saw on SO. I wish custom decoding wasn't so steeped in mystery for so many developers but it's actually fairly straight forward when you get your head around how it works.

Comment: You could use an enum `enum Zone: String, Decodable { zoneA, zoneB...}` for decoding the zone name, this will simplify a little bit the switch, and makes it more robust.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yeah, I really love answering these questions on SO; they're almost always a fun diversion. But yeah, we definitely need more resources for folks to learn how to do this generally. (I'm giving a talk at 360iDev on exactly this in Sep, and it'll probably be the subject of some blog posts once I resurrect my blog.)

Answer (score 1):

the "zone" property is an array of `Zone` objects. so you can decode them like:

```
enum Zone: Decodable {
    case a([ElementA])
    case b([ElementB])
    case c([ElementC])
    case d([ElementD])
    
    enum Name: String, Codable {
        case a = "zoneA"
        case b = "zoneB"
        case c = "zoneC"
        case d = "zoneD"
    }
    
    enum RootKey: CodingKey {
        case name
        case blocks
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RootKey.self)
        let zoneName = try container.decode(Name.self, forKey: .name)
        switch zoneName {
        case .a: try self = .a(container.decode([ElementA].self, forKey: .blocks))
        case .b: try self = .b(container.decode([ElementB].self, forKey: .blocks))
        case .c: try self = .c(container.decode([ElementC].self, forKey: .blocks))
        case .d: try self = .d(container.decode([ElementD].self, forKey: .blocks))
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can filter out anything you like. For example you can pass in the array and get the result you asked in your question:

```
struct Root {
    init(zones: [Zone]) {
        elementsA = zones.reduce([]) {
            guard case let .a(elements) = $1 else { return $0 }
            return $0 + elements
        }
        elementsB = zones.reduce([]) {
            guard case let .b(elements) = $1 else { return $0 }
            return $0 + elements
        }
        elementsC = zones.reduce([]) {
            guard case let .c(elements) = $1 else { return $0 }
            return $0 + elements
        }
        elementsD = zones.reduce([]) {
            guard case let .d(elements) = $1 else { return $0 }
            return $0 + elements
        }
    }
    
    let elementsA: [ElementA]
    let elementsB: [ElementB]
    let elementsC: [ElementC]
    let elementsD: [ElementD]
}
```

---

##### ✅ Benefits:

1. Retain the original structure (array of zones)
2. Handle repeating zones (if server sends more than just one for each zone)